# Use DOS commands to write each line of a text file to new numbered separate text files

Tags: file, parsing, batch-file, text

I'd like to use CMD (DOS) commands to parse a text file. I'd like to read in each line of text and write that line to a new, sequentially numbered file containing only that line. If the input text file has 57 lines, the output will be 57 text files, each one containing one line. Ideally, the filenames of the new files would be the line number from the input text file.

So if the text on line 3 of the input file is "word" (or it could be "3,word" if that makes finding a solution easier), the output would be a file named "3" whose contents is "word" (or "3,word").

Any ideas?

Thanks for thinking about this.

Comment: Please understand this isn't a code writing service. Please post the batch code you have already and we can try to help with your specific challenges.

Comment: That sounds like the least efficient method for everything I can imagine. Do you really NEED all those one-line-files or do you just think, it makes the rest of your code easier?

Answer (score 0):

If none of the lines begin with `:`

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" test.txt') do echo(%%B>"%%A"
```

If lines may begin with `:`

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('findstr /n "^" test.txt') do for /f "delims=:" %%B in ("%%A") do (
  set "line=%%A"
  setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
  echo(!line:*:=!>%%B
  endlocal
)
```

But I agree with Stephan - this does seem like an odd request. There probably is a better way to  accomplish your ultimate goal.